# Contact Request Form not sending emails

Tags: email

I had a question about my contact form on my Expression Engine Site. It just stopped working, it won't send emails and I don't know if it is in the PHP or what? I know there is nothing in the action"", but that's how it always was. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I have: `

```
        <section role="header">

            <ol role="breadcrumbs">
                <li><a href="{path='site_index'}">Home</a></li>
                <li>Request A Quote</li>
            </ol>

            <h2 class="title">Request A Quote</h2>
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </section>

        <section id="request_form">

            {exp:channel:entries channel="pages"}

            {content}

            {/exp:channel:entries}

            <form method="post" action="">
                <fieldset role="user info">
                    <legend>Basic Information</legend>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="name">Your Name<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" />
                            <span class="error" role="name">Please Specify Your Name</span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="right">
                            <label for="company">Name of Your Company</label>
                            <input type="text" name="company" id="company" tabindex="2" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="phone">Contact Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="4" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="right">
                            <label for="email">Email Address<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" />
                            <span class="error" role="email">Please Supply Your E-mail Address</span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="addr">Address<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="addr" id="addr" tabindex="4" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">City<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" tabindex="5" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="state">State<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="state" id="state" maxlength="2" tabindex="6" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="zip">Zip Code<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" maxlength="5" tabindex="7" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset role="project details">
                    <legend>Project Specifics <span class="diagonals"></span></legend>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="type">Building Type<sub>*</sub></label>
                            <select name="type" id="type" tabindex="4">
                                <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture</option>
                                <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                                <option value="Equine">Equine</option>
                                <option value="Pavilion">Pavilion</option>
                                <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">Building Dimensions<sub>*</sub></label>
                            Width <input type="text" name="d_width" id="d_width" tabindex="5" /> 
                            Length <input type="text" name="d_length" id="d_length" tabindex="5" /> 
                            Height <input type="text" name="d_height" id="d_height" tabindex="5" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">Overhead Doors</label>
                            <span>Size</span> <input type="text" name="ohd_size" id="ohd_size" tabindex="5" />
                            <span>Quantity</span> <input type="text" name="ohd_quantity" id="ohd_quantity" tabindex="5" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">Slider Doors</label>
                            <span>Size</span> <input type="text" name="sd_size" id="sd_size" tabindex="5" />
                            <span>Quantity</span> <input type="text" name="sd_quantity" id="sd_quantity" tabindex="5" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">Entry Doors</label>
                            <span>Size</span> <input type="text" name="ed_size" id="ed_size" tabindex="5">
                            <span>Quantity</span> <input type="text" name="ed_quantity" id="ed_quantity" tabindex="5">
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="windows">Windows</label>
                            <span>Quantity</span> <input type="text" name="windows" id="windows" tabindex="5">
                        </li>
                        <li class="left">
                            <label for="city">Overhangs</label>
                            <input type="text" name="overhangs" id="overhangs" tabindex="5">
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li>
                            <label for="city">Colors</label>
                            <input type="text" name="colors" id="colors" placeholder="Siding: Red, Trim: white, etc." tabindex="5" />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset role="message">
                    <legend>Additional Details</legend>
                    <ol class="no_bullets">
                        <li>
                            <label for="details">Please add any extra information that may be helpful in the planning of your project</label>
                            <textarea name="details" id="details" tabindex="5"></textarea>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset role="submit">
                    <input type="hidden" id="process_val" value="rfp" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="6" class="dred_button">
                    <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </section>

    </article>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple thoughts for you to run down.

Might be spam-filter related. Look up your out-going mail logs on your server, they might tell you something interesting.

Also, if your action is blank, it's likely there's a jquery/javascript that's involved in your form process. If you use firebug, pop that open and see if you're getting any errors on the page. I'm guessing there may be something else broken on the page which would, in turn, break scripts related to the form.

Answer (score 0):

Did this occur after an ee upgrade if so check this forum out.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/238309/

Answer (score 0):

You can try ExpressionEngine's Email addon.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/add-ons/email.html#email-contact-form

Also, check the email settings of EE.
Navigate to `Settings->Outgoing Email` and try `PHP mail` in the Protocol section.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try the Email add-on as well.
Also, something else i have done before for this sort of thing is to create a channel to collect the info through a front-end Channel Form, and then use "MX Email From Template" Add-On to send the email. This works real well if you need it nicely or specificly formatted in a way that the Email Addon can't.